# Magento fronted - file not found when admin hosted on different server

Tags: magento, admin, cdn

My website divided in 4 server.

1. Fronted - front.mysite.com
2. Admin panel - admin.mysite.com
3. CDN for Images - cdn.mysite.com
4. Database server

When I upload new product images. It will auto sync on CDN server from admin server. So media folder exits on Admin and CDN server only not in fronted server.

I set cdn.mysite.com media url (secure & unsecure) in admin server.

My issue is product images not display on front.mysite.com server. Other images display properly (category & CMS pages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage() instead of $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(100,100) everywhere in fronted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set Base Media URL as CDN URL with trailing slash? I mean: http://cdn.mysite.com**/**

Comment: Just for test: can you create 'media' folder on CDN, set Base Media URL as http://cdn.mysite.com/media / (with slash) and use this folder for media storing?